# Ansible-inventory gcp_compute plugin underscore added to host group name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to parse an ansible dynamic inventory file by GCE tags using the gcp_compute plugin. It took me a while to manage to run the plugin so that I actually get the hosts correctly however for some reason the ansible-inventory adds an underscore prefix to the group names, even if the prefix is left blank.

Whenever I run the ansible-inventory with the below inventory.gcp.yml file:

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - terzbx
filters:
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags['items']
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /root/deployment/MY_SERVICEACCOUNT.json
```

The output I receive is:

```
 "all": {
     "children": [
         "__built_in_method_items_of_dict_object_at_0x2bc4db0_",
         "_analytics",
         "_consul_server",
         "_dashboardapi",
         "_elasticsearch",
         "_http_server",
         "_https_server",
         "_inventory",
         "_k2bq",
         "_kafka",
         "_kibana",
         "_logstash_k2bq",
         "_logstash_k2es",
         "_mysql",
         "_neo4j",
         "_ssl_offload",
         "_zookeeper",
         "ungrouped"
     ]
```

I would like it to be:

```
 "all": {
     "children": [
         "_built_in_method_items_of_dict_object_at_0x2bc4db0_",
         "analytics",
         "consul_server",
         "dashboardapi",
         "elasticsearch",
         "http_server",
         "https_server",
         "inventory",
         "k2bq",
         "kafka",
         "kibana",
         "logstash_k2bq",
         "logstash_k2es",
         "mysql",
         "neo4j",
         "ssl_offload",
         "zookeeper",
         "ungrouped"
     ]
```

Anyone faced this issue before? Is there anything I can do to get the desired output?

Thanks in advance for helping :)

Comment: Found it under the __init__.py of the ansible inventory plugin. Under _add_host_to_keyed_group, you'll find "prefix" and "separator".
I just added a conditional where if prefix is left blank than the separator is removed.

Comment: Please do consider submitting a pull request to fix that, as it sounds like a good fix. That goes doubly so for that first entry `"built_in_method_items..."` business, which is *for sure* a bug

Answer (score 1):

Stumbling over the same issue you should give this a try:

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - terzbx
filters:
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags['items']
    separator: ''
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /root/deployment/MY_SERVICEACCOUNT.json
```

Comment: I found it to be something related to the way ansible inventory plugin handles these entries. The way around it is described in my first comment.
separator: ''   will have no affect due to that (it always adds "_" separator - even if stated otherwise)